# search a string in Shell script variable

Tags: shell, unix

I have a shell script variable

```
$a = "Hello i am pass"
```

now i want to search for "`pass`" in variable `$a`.

```
if ["$a" == "pass"]; then
echo "`Success`" 
else 
echo "`fail`"
fi
```

Please give me shell script for searching pass keyword to use in above code.

Comment: SO is not a 'write me some code` site. We are happy to help you with your own code though, so after you have tried something and run into a problem, we'll be happy to help.

Comment: @Levon, Sorry i don't understand what you are talking. Can you be clear please ?

Comment: In general SO is for asking about *specific* problems with code that you have already written, not a place to come to and say, "I have this problem, please write me the code to solve it". Perhaps the [StackOverflow FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) can help clarify this.

Comment: @Levon : Pls remove downvote as i modified question & understood all faqs of Stackoverflow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
flag=`echo $a|awk '{print match($0,"pass")}'`;

if [ $flag -gt 0 ];then

    echo "Success";
else
    echo "fail";

fi
```

Comment: It's a bit much to fork `awk`, `grep` etc. just for a string match. I am afraid a lot of people would be copy-pasting this because it is an accepted answer, so run this first (bash/ksh/zsh): `a='Hello i am pass'; [[ "$a" =~ "pass" ]] && echo Success || echo Fail`

Answer (score 14):

Try with this,

```
#!/bin/bash
a="Hello i am pass";
if [ `echo $a | grep -c "pass" ` -gt 0 ]
then
  echo "Success"
else
  echo "Fail";
fi
```

Comment: I think `grep` is safer than the accepted answer using `awk`. On Solaris, he may need `nawk`; while on OS X he may need to use `gawk` from a port.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a more compact way to write this:

```
echo "$a" | grep "pass" && echo "Found." || echo "Not found."
```

You can use braces to put in multiple instructions instead of a simple `echo`:

```
echo "$a" | grep "pass" && {echo "Found.";exit 0} || {echo "Not found.";exit 1}
```

Comment: In this context, use braces `{ }` not parentheses. Sub-shells are not needed here.

Comment: Yes but just substituting the braces is not enough - now your terminal shell will `exit`.  You also need semicolons before closing braces, and spaces after opening braces. `echo "$a" | grep "pass" && { echo "Found."; true; } || { echo "Not found."; false; }`.

Answer (score 1):

today i used extended choice parameter and using execute shell for the string match.
if someone will find same problem anyone can use this

```
if [ `echo $test| grep -c "abc" ` -gt 0 ]
```

then
  echo "Success"
else
  echo "Fail";
fi

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
a="Hello I am Pass"; 
a1="Hello, Passed my First Attempt" 
a2="Passed in First Attempt"

if [[ ${a,,} =~ 'pass' ]]; then echo 'Success'; else echo 'First Attempt in Learning'; fi
```

Comment: I think that's bash only, no?

Answer (score 0):

Short command:

```
OPC="test"
PROD="This is a test"
[[ ${PROD,,} =~ $OPC ]] && echo -n 1 || echo -n 0
```

The answer will be "1" when find "OPC" in "PROD".